# Windows Server 2008 Service pack 2 - Downloading files using .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was wondering whether there is a way to download files using a .bat file.
Bitsadmin.exe no longer works for 2008R2. 
If you could help with this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you could use Powershell like so:

`(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://www.google.co.uk", "c:\temp\tempfile.txt"`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I'm kind of only working with the batch files as TCADMIN2 only supports that.

Answer (score 1):

With a bat file, *calling* powershell, as I do in [`senv.bat`](https://github.com/VonC/senv/blob/master/senv.bat):

```
@echo off

@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "& \"C:\path\to\ascript.ps1\"" %*
```

Then a `script.ps1` can call `DownloadFile` as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21477673/6309) by [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280587/paul).

That same powershell command can actually be called from a regular shell:

```
C:\> @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://an/url','c:/temp/aFile')"
```